# Module installed according to pip freeze but unable to import in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

**Please Read the complete question before marking it duplicate**

I am trying to import to a module 'rapidjson' and inside my virtual environment created by 'pipenv'. All of the other imports and pip installs work fine except this particular one.

I've tried different solutions from stack overflow like:

Might be a permission issue (read/write).
Not activated your pipenv.
Use python -m pip install 
Import using python -c "import rapidjson"

But still haven't found any solutions.
The module import works fine outside the virtual environment.
rapidjson==1.0.0

[image: Error Report]

Comment: Maybe you mean [`python-rapidjson`](https://pypi.org/project/python-rapidjson/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rapidjson` 1.0.0 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/rapidjson/1.0.0/#files) one wheel. I downloaded it and extracted (a wheel is just a zip archive). It contains `setuptools`' metadata but not any code. There is nothing to import and execute.

The only version is 1.0.0, published in 2018. The "Homepage" (supposedly from `setup.py`) points to https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject.

Resume — the package is broken and abandoned. Forget about it. You're probably looking for the package https://pypi.org/project/python-rapidjson/

```
pip install python-rapidjson
```